# Fast approximate 2D distance formula

Tags: circles

I want to compute 2D distance faster.
We all know the base formula:
$$
\left(x\right)^{2}+\left(y\right)^{2}=r^{2}
$$
but it require
$$
\sqrt{r}
$$
which is very heavy computing, my case is 4 millions loop.

I've made this formula
$$
a=\frac{\left|x\right|+\left|y\right|}{2\max\left(\left|x\right|,\left|y\right|\right)}
$$
$$
\frac{\left(a\left(\left|x\right|+\left|y\right|\right)+2\left(1-a\right)\cdot\max\left(\left|x\right|,\left|y\right|\right)\ \right)}{1.5}=\ r
$$
which doesn't require to calculate the square root at all! It is low accuracy but it is acceptable.

[Desmos's graph showcase](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/aioreppxzx)

Are there any quicker distance calculating than this? Thank you very much!

---

**Update**

I know this not a good way to approximate the distance, compare to the square root one. So that is why I am asking to learn any better formula (faster calculating) available. Thanks!

p/s: Not so much precision is need but need to be more precise than the Manhattan distance.

Comment: Just an interest, what is the tool you are using that needs that much to calculate the square root?

Comment: Why would you need such an approximation? Current algorithms are fast enough for calculating $\sqrt r$ and almost all of the programming languages implement it.

Comment: This is much much more expensive than a square root

Comment: It depends upon your application. For example, if you want to determine if two points are within a certain distance of each other you can just use the square of the distance instead.

Comment: "This is much much more expensive than a square root " indeed , there is no gain using this expression.

Comment: @Yalikesifulei I am a game developer and I am trying implement faster way to approximate distance than the original square root, in C#.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici and Peter : Yes I think so too, so I am asking if any quicker formula (for computer) available.

Comment: @John Douma you mean the manhattan distance? Yes that is the fastest way (depend on what I know) to approximate the distance. Now in my case need something that between the precise distance and manhattan distance.

Comment: @KhangDinhHoang No. If you are writing a game, for example, and you want to record a hit on a target if the missile comes within a distance $d$ of the target, then you can use $d^2$ instead. This avoids the computation of the square root and you get the same accuracy.

Comment: @John Douma Thank you very much for that!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root might help. has always intrigued me

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}r&=x\sqrt{1+\left (\frac{y}{x}\right)^2}, x\ne 0\\
&=x\cdot \sec t, \tan t=\frac{y}{x}\end{align}$$

If x=0 then you factor the y.

If you implemented a table of secants then you’re a linear interpolation (or a mean average) plus a multiplication away from the result.